# Testing in specific namespace

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test some classes in namespace, currently I have this code:

```
describe Server::SessionController do

  it "should create session" do
    Server::LoginController.stub(:authenitcate).and_return(session_id)
    Server::SessionController....
    Server::SessionController....
  end
end
```

How to get rid of repeatable `Server` namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RSpec Book ( http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book ) gives a solution :

```
3 module Codebreaker
4    describe Game do
5        describe "#start" do
```

> ... The second statement declares a Ruby module named Codebreaker.This isn’t necessary in
>   order to run the specs, but it provides some conveniences. For
>   example, we don’t have to fully qualify Game on line 4.

So, try to put your spec inside a `Server` module.
HTH.

Answer (score 2):

While @BernardK gave "the-right-thing" solution that will suit for most cases, there is also a dirty HACK. It may be useful if you have a lot of different Spec files testing different classes from the same namespace, and tired of writing `module Your::Long::Namespace ... end` in every file and introducing additional identation level (as this may cause giant diffs in your VCS).

So, if you put this...

```
def Object.const_missing(c)
  if Your::Long::Namespace.const_defined? c
    Your::Long::Namespace.const_get(c)
  else
    raise NameError, "uninitialized constant #{c}"
  end
end
```

...in your `spec_helper.rb`, then in every spec using this helper you will be able to use all constants from `Your::Long::Namespace` (classes are constants too) without prefix and without need to put your specs inside this module. This is very much like C++'s `using namespace` statement. You can see an example of using this in one of my old projects: [definition here](https://github.com/moonlighters/webobots/blob/master/spec/emulation_system_helper.rb#L30), [usage example here](https://github.com/moonlighters/webobots/blob/master/spec/lib/emulation_system/emulation/missile_spec.rb#L38).

BUT note that:

- this violates all thinkable OOP principles;
- you modify the behaviour of **all** Objects, some code might not expect this;
- as with C++ `using namespace`, this causes namespace clutter and possible conflicts;
- being silent and not taking attention (which is *good*), this hack is very unobvious and undebugabble (which is *very BAD*, especially if you have collaborators).

You see, use at your own risk :)

Comment: I'm quite new to RSpec, I bookmark your trick. And I learned `const_missing` :) Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful :) Also note its brother, `method_missing`, which allows writing fantastic DSLs by letting objects handle methods that were not actually defined (ActiveRecord does it for table fields). Some hacks are also possible, like [here](https://gist.github.com/4603084) you make ruby dictionaries behave like Javascript ones :)